# vim E365: Failed to print Postscript File

Tags: vim

I don't print from vim often, so I am not sure when this happened.

I cannot print (ha[rdcopy] from vim or gVim.

I get the error

```
E365: Failed to print Postscript File
```

I am running on Ubuntu 10.04.

I am looking for ideas on things to configure as well as anyone who has had experience with this problem and might have an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a lot of clues there...

Starting Vim with verbose turned on `gvim -V`
and doing `:hardcopy` might produce some clues.

Also, this might also be useful `:set printexpr?`

You can also check if the regular command `lps` is working, and whether you have the default printer set up correctly. Another useful command is `set pdev=printer_name`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error when my system had two printers configured with no default. Setting a default resolved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent answer above. A few other pointers I'd like to share after just printing from Vim for the first time:

- You can find your printer name in Ubuntu by checking the CUPS interface at http://localhost:631/printers/
- To print without the file name header use:

  `set popt=paper:letter,header:0`
- Finally, you can print using:

  `hardcopy`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to set a default printer I fixed it installing *gtklp*:

```
$ sudo apt install gtklp
```